# How do you make a HTML table partially transparent?

Tags: html, html-table, transparent

If I have a HTML table like the one below:

```
<table bgcolor="#151515" height="100" width="200">
<tr>
<td>
Hello
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How can I make it partially transparent? Is there a way of doing it without CSS? If not what is the CSS way?

Comment: you mean so that the background looks 'cloudy', or 'dimmed'?

Comment: Hi guys sorry I missed out the word transparent! So yes how can I make a table transparent?

Comment: Why would you want to do it without CSS? CSS is a far better way of doing it.

Comment: Oh I was just having a bit of trouble opening up a new document to make a css file but its fine now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try this in your html file:

```
<table class='table1'>
<tr><td>...
```

And this in your css file:

```
.table1 {
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

This sets the rgba RED GREEN BLUE ALPHA values, 255,255,255 = white, 0,0,0 = black, and the 0.5 value at the end (ALPHA) is between 0 and 1, where 1 is opaque and 0 is transparent. I hope this helps.

In your case, #151515 (HEX CODE) translates to (21, 21, 21, 0.5) (RGBA) where A is equal to 50% transparent.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the opacity or transparency of the background in CSS, as follows

```
  /* for IE */
   filter:alpha(opacity=60);
   /* CSS3 standard */
   opacity:0.6;
```

The above makes it 60% clear. Hope this helps.

Comment: Opacity will apply to not only the background, but also the text and all elements inside it.

Comment: ah, I didn't realize that. He could then set different styles for the text & other content of the table.

Comment: The problem is that all opacities under that become relative to the parent's opacity. So the maximum opacity that can be achieved by any child element is now set to 0.6. See this [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/animuson/fJKfh/1/).

Answer (score 1):

The way to change the background color and opacity is adding this attribute to your css.

`background-color: rgba(100,200, 0, 0.5);` (not background)

If you want to change the background+text content opacity, you can use:

`opacity:0.6;`

Answer (score 0):

With CSS you set the `opacity` to a value between 0 and 1.  However, that will make any element inside your table transparent.

A better solution (unfortunately) is to make a tiling background png with slight transparency.  That way you can fade the background without fading the content.

Answer (score 0):

Replying to old post but this is still relevant as I just referenced it =)

Too... you can use fireworks or (presumably) photoshop to create an all black .png image (just a black box).  Set your desired transparency with the toolbar and set said photo as your table background image.  It defaults to repeat itself so will fill your table.  You will have a transparent table that you can see your -body bg img/color- through and anything you put into the table will be unaffected by the transparency.

Jon